# String length limitation using dbBind of DBI in R

Tags: r, sql-update, prepared-statement, r-dbi

I want to use DBI::dbBind to run some parameterized queries to update a SQL Server database but the string values I wrote got truncated at 256 characters.  In the code below, I am supposed to see a string of 500 "n" in the database but I only see 256.

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "xxx", Server = "serverx", Database = "dbx", UID = "pathx", PWD = "passwd", PORT = 1234)

query <- "UPDATE tableA SET fieldA = ? WHERE rowID = ?"

para <- list(strrep("n", 500), "id12345")

sentQuery <- dbSendQuery(conn, query)
dbBind(sentQuery, para)
dbClearResult(sentQuery)
```

I also tried writing the 500 "n" without using dbBind, and the result is fine. I see all 500 n. I guess this eliminates some culprits of the problem, like the conn and the field definition in the database. This is the code that works.

```
query <- (paste0("UPDATE tableA SET fieldA = '", strrep("n", 500), "' WHERE rowID = 'id12345'"))

dbExecute(conn, query)
```

I found one similar question without answer ([Truncated updated string with R DBI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964633/truncated-updated-string-with-r-dbi-package)).  However that question didn't point out dbBind therefore I am posting this for higher specificity.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. To start, I created a table with `"create table tableA (fieldA nvarchar(max), rowID nvarchar(32))"`, ensuring that the fields are big enough. I then ran your code exactly, and the length of `fieldA` is indeed 500. Since you say that it works for you when you run it literally (second code block), I wonder if your real data has an encoding issue that might differentiate literal versus `dbBind`. Are there any diacritics, unicode, or something else not-simple-ASCII in your real data?

Comment: Thanks for testing things out for me.  To answer your encoding question - I in fact used the strrep("n") to validate the issue, therefore any encoding issue can be eliminated.  The fact that you cannot reproduce the issue sparked an idea on me.  Perhaps you have a different DBI version? My DBI is version 1.0.0.  May I know yours?

Comment: I'm using `DBI-1.1.2` and `odbc-1.3.3`

Comment: I have updated my DBI to 1.1.2 but the problem is still there. My odbc is version 1.1.6 which could be the one causing all the problems.  However I run into a bunch of challenges updating the odbc (I don't have root access).  I will report back to this post if I have any useful discovery.  In the meantime, I will rely on the literal method to get the job done.

Comment: It might be informative to show what the database thinks is the table schema: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='tableA'`.